# Is there a state machine framework which implements UML semantics for the D programming language?

Tags: d, state-machine, fsm

Is there a state machine framework in the D programming language which implements UML semantics similar to boost.MSM, boost.statecharts, QP or Machine Objects ?

Comment: None widely known at least.

Comment: hmmm maybe bounty will help, this is the only show stopper in my migration of a project to D

Comment: I doubt there is something like `boost.MSM` in the D world.

Comment: You can consider using [Interfacing to C](http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html) or [Interfacing to C++](http://dlang.org/cpp_interface.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) says it has a D backend.